# Why is $f:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is a "figure of six" a counterexample for injective immersion $\implies$ embedding?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

We have that any embedding is an injective immersion. My notes give a counterexample for the converse (that any injective immersion is an embedding) as the mapping $f:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is a "figure of six".

This mapping is clearly invertible, smooth, and the inverse is smooth. So it is a diffeomorphism. It is also injective, but its derivative $d_xf$ is not injective ($d_xf = 0$ at the top and bottom of the six, for example). Thus it is injective but not an immersion. Why have my notes given it as an example of an injective immersion not being an embedding?

Comment: The inverse of the injective immersion is not a diffeomorphism; consider open neighbourhoods of the tripoint of the figure six.

Comment: @Servaes but why is $f$ an immersion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slightly subtle. It is *not* a homeomorphism onto its image in the subspace topology. Indeed, given a topological space $X$ and a subset $Y\subseteq X$, the subspace topology of $Y$ inherited from that on $X$ says that the open subsets of $Y$ are those of the form $U\cap Y$ for $U$ open in the topology on $X$.

Let $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb{R}^2$ denote the figure-six map. In this case, you should think about what the open neighborhoods of the point at the "join" between the loop of the $6$ and the stem of the $6$ (the point of almost intersection) are in the *subspace topology*. Now, can you find a reason why such an $f$ cannot be a homeomorphism?

As for your question about the immersion: you should think more carefully about the differential. If you parametrize the map appropriately, the differential will be zero at no point in the domain. Indeed, you can think of having a particle traversing the figure $6$ in time $t\in [0,1)$ without stopping.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what you're saying. The map $f$ is continuous, so the preimage of open sets is open. The inverse is not continuous, though.